# How useful is DRAKE toolbox

Tags: robotics-toolbox, robotics-system-toolbox

How useful would it be to learn and interact with DRAKE toolbox that is open source? Are there better toolboxes out there when compared with the DRAKE toolbox?
I am a student interested in robotics and wanted to understand what are things that the DRAKE toolbox can or cannot do when compared with other toolboxes?

Comment: HI i will attempt to rephrase the question better if it seems unclear. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Hari, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Choosing how to spend your time (books to read, classes to take, projects to construct, career to pursue etc.) may be difficult, but it's specific to you, so unlikely to help future visitors. Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].

Comment: @Ben Thank you for pointing that out. Appreciate the links that you have provided on how to ask questions and the robotics chat!